# Extracting multiple numerical values from mixed characters in excel worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a column containing cells with two numerical values, separated by an asterix...

e.g. 12.5*3.4

How can i extract the smaller number of the two into one new column, and the larger of the two into another separate new column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your cell with the data is A1, this will give you the smaller of the two:

`=MIN(LEFT(A1,FIND("*",A1)-1),RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("*",A1)))`

To get the bigger, change the `MIN` to `MAX`.

Comment: THANKS, just saved me about 9 hours work, much appreciated!!!!